# how are offsets determined when implicitly up-casting?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Left
{
   char i = 'k';
};

struct Right
{
   int a = 99;
};

struct Bottom : Left, Right
{};

int main()
{
    Bottom b;

    Left* l = &b;
    cout << l->i;

    Right* r = &b;
    cout << r->a;

    return 0;    
}
// output
// k99
```

How did this work?

if the memory layout of Bottom is:

```
Left
Right
Bottom
```

Then slicing `b` (i.e. `Bottom`) to `Left` object, should be ok, but how can it work when I slice `Bottom` to `Right` object?

Why isn't static casting required in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the compiler knows the types of both pointers, it can apply the necessary offset adjustment. If you print out the values of the pointers, you'll see that they're a bit different.